# Some questions about strict tableau in propositional calculus (raising from a book by Melvin Fitting)

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving

Recently, I encountered some questions when reading *First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving* (1st ed - 1990), by Melvin Fitting.

1: confusing  definition of strict tableau (page 39 definition 3.14).I can understand if we focus on all branches of the construction of tableau , thus it means that we never apply some rule to same formula more than once in a branch. But how we gain a general description of "strict tableau"?

2:In prolog, we guarantee a strict construction of tableau by simply removing formula we have used in branch. Thus, tableau expansion rule become identical dual clause set reduction rule, then, the construction become the manipulation from ordinary formula to normal form, the number of which yield finite since konig lemma. Finite guarantee it works in prolog.... It seems natural but I feel somewhat ambiguous between the version of "remove" in prolog and construction of strict tableau. Such as, could contradiction occur in some formulas which have removed?...

Briefly, could anyone make some more explicit explanation to me?     Wish your help, thanks!

Comment: not sure what you mean, maybe if you copy the definition from the book, mostly in the tableau method you only need to aply a rule only once on a formula , but i never heard of a strict tableau, the blurb of the second edition says that the second edition gives the prolog programs as well maybe that will help you

Comment: @Willemien:"A tableau is strict If in its construction no formula has had a Tableau Expansion Rule applied to it twice On the same branch" from the book of Melvin fitting. However, same formula in distinct branches can be used independently (Data structure of Tableau in prolog:a list of lines , each line is some branch in Tableau), as Melvin said, we can pick one branch (line) which some non-literal formula occur in, then apply rule to the non-literal formula, since we will never use the picked formula again, we simply remove it in the picked branch.

Comment: @Willemien: maybe the same non-literal formula occur in other branches , they will survive after the application. Furthermore, if we remove the non-literal formula in picked branch,tableau expansion rule become identical dual clause set reduction rule. I want to know more explicit detail how we deal with Tableau in prolog? Could you recommend some books about semantic Tableau, or prolog?    Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about propositional (without quantifiers)or predicate logic (with quantifiers) at the moment?
still I advice you for the moment just to stick to the book you have (if you have the second/last edition)  I think you are bothered about a minor detail (it is just to keep /make the procedure efficient, but it will come back later to proof the decidability / undecidability of the propositional / predicate case i guess ) but this is all without having even seen the book , do also have a look at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see Marcello D'Agostino & Dov Gabbay (editors), *Handbook of Tableau Methods* (1998): M.D'Agostino, *TABLEAU METHODS FOR CLASSICAL PROPOISTIONAL LOGIC*, page 70-71.

In the context of Proof-search with Smullyan’s Tableaux, you can see the definition of *regular* tableaux:

> A tableau is said to be *regular* if no formula occurs more than once in each branch.
>
> Suppose that in the construction of a tableau $\mathcal T$ we come across a branch $\phi$  containing both a node $k$ labelled with a formula $\beta$ and a node $m$ labelled with $\beta_i$ (with i = 1 or i = 2). Among the many useless moves that one can make when
>   applying the tableau rules mechanically, one of the worst consists in applying the $\beta$-decomposition rule to the formula $\beta$ in $\phi$, because one of the two branches generated by the rule application will contain another copy of $\beta_i$. [see graph]
>
> Let us say that a node $k$ subsumes a node $m$ if $m$ is labelled with a formula $\beta$ and $k$ is labelled with one of its components $\beta_i$. We can often spare a large number of branchings if we agree that a node which is subsumed by another node in a given branch $\phi$ is *not* used in $\phi$ as premiss of an application of the $\beta$-decomposition
>   rule. This is, somehow, implicit in the procedure to construct a completed tableau described [above], if we simply agree that the $\beta$-decomposition rule should not be applied, in a given branch $\phi$, to a $\beta$-formula labelling a node which is already ‘fulfilled’ in $\phi$. It is not difficult to construct examples showing that this obvious ‘economy principle’ in the application of the tableau rules may, on some occasions, shorten proofs (or in general completed tableaux) by an exponential factor.
>
> As far as the propositional rules are concerned, the regularity restriction implies the basic condition called *strictness*, namely that no formula is used more than once as a premiss of a rule application. Things are different in the first order case for which we refer the reader to R.Letz’s chapter [*FIRST-ORDER TABLEAU METHODS*] in this *Handbook*.

I'm in trouble with tree, so I'll try to describe the example.

We want to check if $\{ p \lor q, q \lor r \} \vDash p \land r$. We build a tableau for :

> $\{ Tp \lor q, Tq \lor r, Fp \land r \}$.

When we have fulfilled $Tp \lor q$, we have two branches (we have applied a $\beta$-rule), one with $Tp$ as $\beta_1$ and the other with $Tq$ as $\beta_2$.

With the second step, we fulfill $Tq \lor r$; again apply a $\beta$-rule, so we have to branch both the previous branches. But (form left to right) the third branch have already $Tq$; so we may forget of the $\beta_1$ new branch.

With a computer program, you must check if a formula $\beta_i$ is already present and, if so, avoid to write the branch; in this way, the proof-search algorithm can avoid (in case of complex formulas) unnecessary branches.

Comment: ：your answer is what I want !! I have ever tried to consult the "handbook" you recommanded,i found it too huge to find the description of "strict tableau" . you have helped me before with patience .SINCERELY THANK YOU ! !

Comment: @RussellThomas - you are welcome :)

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA:trivial problem:when we bulid a tableau for {Tp∧p},thus we gain the unqiue branch :Tp∧p，Tp,Tp.   or without the last Tp?  for the former branch : Although no formula is used more than once (that is strictness),it is not regular (since Tp occurs twice).

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA:In your example, you forget of the β1 new branch,should the definition of tableau(from smullyan or Melvin Fitting) be modified since we omit some branches ?  Furthermore,we can convert a ordinary formula to disjunctive normal form using same rules like β-rule ,However,we remove  picked non-literal formula which is replaced by new formulas（eg：followin α-rule）.I want to proof method of tableau  yield finite since manipulation of coverting to disjunctive normal form yield finite (since konig lemma).

Comment: @RussellThomas - the problem, I suppose, is only with computer programs that elaborate complex formulas. If you run the tableau by hand, you can avoid "cutting" branches. But if you have $Tp \land p$ you are not branching; so the only problem is to duplicate or not $Tp$ in the same branch: and this have no effect (the duplication); so, I presume you can write it once.